# Identify polygon touching common polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, spatial-join

[image]

In the case of the image towards left, the red polygon is overlapping the blue polygons.

In the case of the image towards right, two red polygons are overlapping blue polygons. The two red polygons are overlapping on one common polygon, i.e. polygon no. 2.

Is there any way to identify the polygons, i.e. particularly those polygons in which 2 or more red polygons are overlapping on a common blue polygon?

Comment: Search the help file for the Polygon Neighbors (Analysis) tool, that can generate all sorts of statistics about polygon contiguity

Comment: Are the red and blue polygons in the same feature class?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Here is one if you want to know how many red polygons are overlapping the blue:

1. Assign a value of 1 to each the red polygons (add field, make sure its double and use the field calculator to assign it a value of 1), make sure the red polygons are multipart (unique entities), make sure the blue polygons all have unique names / identifiers
2. Perform an intersect between the red and blue polygons
3. Run a dissolve on the newly created intersected, use the blue polygon identifier as the dissolve field and choose the field you created in step 1 as the statistics field. It will show as a red error until you choose the statistics type. Make sure you choose SUM.

While "SUM" isnt really necessary, you can also use "COUNT", I chose this method to make sure it works.

4. The output shapefile will have an attibute table with the name of the blue polygon that has an overlap, and a field called SUM which will tell you home many red polygons overlap it.
5. You can use a table join to get the count of red overlaps back to the original blue polygons. You can use the name field as the link.

Other options to look at would be a spatial join. I can outline that method if this method doesn't work for you.